# Problem with minimizing effect in my Unity on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: unity, compiz, bug-reporting

This is strange. You know how Unity has a fading effect when you minimize? Now it's faster than usual. If I reset Unity's settings, it fixes it, but then after a while, the effect slowly gets faster again, to the point it's fast. Why does it do this, it's annoying and strange, because it happens automatically. I got Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase `minimize time` using compizConfig setting manager.

after this:

1. open compiz from dash by typing `ccsm`
2. Under `Categories` open `Effects`
3. then search for `Animations` and then open `Minimize Animation` tab. change `duration` there as shown in image

[image: CompizConfig setting manager Animation]

Comment: It didn't work. It's still speedy. I want it at stock speed, like when I installed it.

Comment: In fact, strangely, it's barely even changing. :\

Comment: try bigger value like 500 - 700 it will show difference

Comment: I tried that before you asked me, even at 4000 it was faster than normal. :\

Comment: cant help beyond this. ihad recommend you not to spend your precious time on it

Comment: Is it a bug? A virus? I don't know what's happening. Do I need to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: it must be bug, virus highly impossible. need not to reinstall, just ignore it

Comment: Is there a way to reinstall unity itself?

Comment: yes. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and then `sudo apt-get install unity`

Comment: It says Unity's already installed. I doesn't reinstall it

Comment: use tty, then purge both ubuntu-desktop and unity and then install it again. to use tty press Ctrl + Alt+F4. to come back to GUI press CTRL+ALT+F7

Comment: I found out it is a bug, ran a live DVD, and the bug still happened. Hopefully Canonical will fix this.

Comment: @RoundDuckMan you can email this bug to canonical, be sure to give your hardware details properly and complete